# Как сделать вложенную маршрутизацию в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, route, router

Есть страница `/Products` на которой отображаются товары с разных категорий.
Необходимо выводить дочерние элементы:
`/Products/phone` - страница телефонов
`/Products/pc` - страница компьютеров и т.д.
Как сделать так, что бы `/Products` стал родительским, а я лишь указывал дочерние роуты? Нужно что то типа того:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path='/Products'>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/phone' render={() => <Phone />} />
          <Route path='/pc' render={() => <Pc />} />
        </Switch>
    </Route>
</BrowserRouter>
```

P.S. Не предлагайте прописывать путь для каждой категории. Все эти категории будут динамическими и URL зависить будет от названия. + подкатегории будут. Нужно решение именно в духе вложенных роутов

Comment: Думаю это вам поможет лично не пользовался так как версия новая https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#introducing-routes

Answer (score 0):

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route exact path='/'>
      <Redirect to='/Products' component = { Product } />
   </Route>
  <Route path='/Products'/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

В твоем продакт

```js
       <Switch>
          <Route path=`${match.path}/phone`component={<Phone />} />
          <Route path=`${match.path}/pc` component={<Pc />} />
        </Switch>
```

Только match деструктуризируй